# Fetching data in case of one -to- many relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables users, user_group, and groups.

users have one to many relationship with groups.

If I want to fetch only those users who don't have group Mathematics.

I have using the following query for this purpose:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_group ON user_group.user_id = user.UserID 
INNER JOIN groups ON user_group.group_id = groups.group_id
WHERE groups.Name <> 'Mathematics';
```

But it is returning multiple records against all Users. Suppose, if I have user John and he joined 3 groups Science, Mathematics and English. In this case, it will return two records of user John. I want to remove user John totally from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users AS u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM user_group AS ug 
                  INNER JOIN groups AS g ON ug.group_id = g.group_id
                  WHERE ug.user_id = u.UserID AND g.Name = 'Mathematics');
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4502e0/4)

If you want to do it using joins, then this is a way:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM user_group 
  INNER JOIN groups 
    ON user_group.group_id = groups.group_id AND groups.Name = 'Mathematics'
) AS g ON u.UserID = g.user_id
WHERE g.user_id IS NULL
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4502e0/8)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN user_group ON user.UserID = user_group.user_id
LEFT JOIN groups ON user_group.group_id = groups.group_id
WHERE groups.Name != 'Mathematics';
```

Comment: it returns multiple entries of the user against groups. e.g. john with group science and john with group english. basically, I want to eliminate user john completely from list.